# Javascript : How to write (*) in New regex

Tags: javascript, regex

How to write (*) in New Regex using javascript ? The following doesn't work for me.

```
var matcher = new RegExp('this is a sample text \\(/\*/\\) and this this the rest of the text after.', 'g');
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Literal `*` or quantifier `*`?

Comment: literal please : it's inside the sentence : 'All items marked with (*) are required, please  fill in...'

Comment: This `\\(/\*/\\)` should be `\\(/\\*/\\)` because `"\*"` is just `*` but `"\\*"` is `\*`.

Comment: You probably could just use a regexp literal instead of a constructor here.

Comment: Thank you Ibrahim but It return invalid regular expression :unmatched parentheses. Should miss something. I need (*)

Comment: Ok, work now. Thank you

Comment: **`[*]`** may be

Answer (score 2):

Write it like `\\(\\*\\)`.

Working backward from the desired result:

You want the literal characters `(*)`.

All three are special characters in a Regex, so escape them: `\(\*\)`.

But `\` is a special character in JavaScript string literals, so escape it: `\\(\\*\\)`.

Finally:

```
var matcher = new RegExp('this is a sample text \\(\\*\\) and this this the rest of the text after.', 'g');
```